# Does the regex library in C# System.Text.RegularsExpressions ignore some minors faults?

Tags: c#, regex

So I have a program that is used to clean string. One such cleaning is to get rid of surrounding characters. By exemple : "this is my text" => this is my text

For that, I use a regex and one part of it is :

`@"(^+" + '"' + ".*" + '"' + "$)"`

The + after the ^ isn't needed and when removed, it works without problem. However I remarked that even with it, the program. But I wrote this part of the program two month ago so I a not 100% sure if it was a typo or not.

So my question : Is it possible that some minors errors in regex construction will be ignored (/deleted during compilation ?) as long as they do not have any sense in the "regex world" ?

I expected that a wrongly entered characters in a regex would either incur an error or at best would incur the regex to be ignored.

I tested with and without it in a regex corrector (regex101), confirming that the + is seen as wrong according to regex rules.

Regex to test :

```
(^+".*"$)
```

I tested with and without it in a simple compiler and both do the exast same work when they are tasked with removal.

Compiler code :

```
public static void Main()
{
    string artist = "\"an artist\"";
    if (surroundingRegex.IsMatch(artist))
    {
    artist = artist[1..^1];
    }
    Console.WriteLine(artist);
}
    
public static readonly Regex surroundingRegex = new(@"(^+" + '"' + ".*" + '"' + "$)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

Comment: I don't know C#, but I believe you can write `@"(^+"".*""$)"` (escape double-quotes by duplicating) instead of `@"(^+" + '"' + ".*" + '"' + "$)"`.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but a good resource for checking this in the future is https://regex101.com/ On the website you can choose which "flavor" (programming language) of regex you're using.

Answer (score 0):

`^+` means *one or more line beginnings*. You have just one, so it works even if it's strange.

It's definitely a so-called [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell). You should examine your code for regexes from that period of development to see if there are other problems.

**Pro tip** Many programmers avoid using regexes unless we have no viable alternative, because they're not easy to inspect or test.

Comment: When you said that it is "one or more beginnings", are you speaking about what it could mean (if it existed) or that it actually exists and is used as an effective rule ?

Comment: `W+` means *one or more W characters*. `^` is a special regex character -- an anchor character -- that matches the beginning of whatever text you give the regex. (`$` is the other anchor character, it matches the end.) So `^+` is weird. One or more line-beginnings? There's only one, so it works. It's not a regex syntax error, but other than that it just means `^`.